# TextView only updates once

Tags: textview, android

I'm having a seemingly strange issue with my android app.
Whether I call append or setText, my TextView will only update once.

I have my IME set to have a "Send" button that listens as follows:

```
        sendText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND){
                try {
                    send();
                    scroller.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("chat", e.toString());
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The send method:

```
public void send(){
    final String message = sendText.getText().toString();
    final String ip = ipAddr.getText().toString();
    //rcvMsg.append("Me:  " + message + "\n");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            TextView rcv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rcvMsg);
            rcv.setText(rcv.getText()+"Me: "+message+"\n");
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I tried append and a setText in runOnUiThread. Both of those only update the textView the first time send() is called. On subsequent calls, it doesn't change.

**But!**

If I put the app in the background (hit home), then relaunch it, the TextView has all the proper text.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've tried rcvMsg.invalidate(), but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out - it was a GUI issue..

I accidentally set the height of the TextView (inside a scrollview) to an exact value. Apparently, this caused the fullScroll method to screw up and not scroll down completely, so the added text was invisible. Setting the height of the TextView to wrap_content solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put below line of code after `setContentView` in your activity and remove from send method

```
TextView rcv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rcvMsg);
```

Change this line `rcv.setText(rcv.getText()+"Me: "+message+"\n");`
 to

```
rcv.setText(rcv.getText().toString()+"Me: "+message+"\n");
```

in send method

Comment: No luck. Still has the same issue.

Comment: Nothing. The TextView still won't update until I back out and reload the app.

Comment: this is the last resort I can advice you try rcv.invalidate() after setting text

Comment: Thought of that before I posted here, and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put

```
TextView rcv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rcvMsg);
rcv.setText(rcv.getText()+"Me: "+message+"\n");
```

In a runnable.  Your code should look more like this.

```
public void send(){

    TextView rcv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rcvMsg);
    rcv.setText(rcv.getText()+"Me: "+sendText.getText().toString()+"\n");

}
```

If you are sending this message using the ip variable somehow you would do that inside of a runable, but setting the textarea inside of a runable is impossible seeing as the two are running on separate threads.

Comment: Nothing doing. Changing the send message to just those two lines doesn't help. The TextView will still not update until I back out of and reload the app.

Comment: Try logging the TextView before and after you set it. Log.d("before", rcv.getText());  and see if log cat sees the change.  If log cat is not picking it up you have the TextView.setText running in a separate thread from your UI.